# Conversion of Access desktop database to Access web database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I require help on below:

1. I am trying to compile a Report from a Access form by entering values separated using comma and at the click of a button,a Report should be exported for those values. otherwise we will have to look out manually for 100 such records daily.
2. I want to update the status for selected records by using records selectors, where I will select few and change the Cheque status Combo box from the form header.
3. Currently I am building it as an desktop database. How to convert it as Web database and share it on the web?

Answer (score 1):

The first issue to deal with is #3. There is no technology that exists today that can take a typical car and convert that car into say an airplane. In other words, unless the car is designed from the ground up to fly, then the car will not fly. This issue of converting desktop applications is not restricted to Access, but really quite much any and all desktop development systems (they are the WRONG TOOL if you wish to build a web application).

So if you going to build an airplane, then you want and need to design the thing you are building as an aircraft.

Thus if you going to build a web application, then you want and need to design the application as web based FROM THE START. No conversion of the desktop applications to web exists. You could however consider having the desktop application run on a server via Terminal services and have the client desktops thus use RDP, or even utilize a RDP to HTML5 bridge. However without knowing what service providers you plan to choose or have now, such answers are much speculation.

So you need to create and start with a web based application if using Access. You also then need to determine who to use for web  hosting (since VERY few support access web services). And fewer support reports for Access. For example with Access web publishing to office 365 on-line the setup currently does not support reports. However if you have your own SharePoint server, then you can build reports with Access web development (Access web 2010 only – 2013,2016 don’t support web reports).

A discussion of web development on a simple post here is not practical – such answers as to how to build and deploy a web based application would take 100’s of pages for a proper response. (however there is this thing called google – you need to do some reading on web development).

As for updating records by using selectors? That is difficult in desktop, and even more of a challenge for Access web. A far more simple approach would be to add a check box column to the continues form, allow the user to check the rows, and then setup some code to process those rows. (for Access web, that would mean your form would call a data macro that then processes the rows that have the checkbox column marked as true).

Same goes for filtering a web report by comma separated values. For desktop, you can use the SQL “in” clause and thus create a report “where” clause. However for web based, you don’t have use of the sql “in” command, so a different approach will be required. I would suggest perhaps setting up a form with a sub form, and you thus can type in each number on a separate row of the sub form – this then could be processed.

Last but not least:

If you going to start web development with Access, it is strongly recommended that you use Access 2013 for web development, as they significantly changed how Access web development works, and there is thus no migration from Access web 2010 to web 2013.

Comment: Require suggestions to make an field automatic update based on the System date.  Example: I want a feild to be updated daily based on the system date with condition being any thing lesser than today.

Comment: I would start a new question. However, a update query with the correct criteria should allow such a update.